# How do I force join inside a left join branch?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, left-join

I need to LEFT join to entire t2+t3 branch, but if I can find a matching join between t1 and t2, I want to enforce the t2 and t3 join.

```
   SELECT T1.name,T2.bob,T3.a
     FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
     JOIN T3 ON t2.id = T3.t2_id
```

What is the syntax?

Sample data:

```
T1 [id,name]
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc

T2 [id,t1_id,bob]
1,1,777
2,1,888
2,2,999

T3[id,t2_id,a]
1,2,'yeh'
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
 [name] , [a]   , [bob]
  aaa   , 'yeh' , 888
  bbb   , NULL  , NULL
  ccc   , NULL  , NULL
```

Comment: So do you want to exclude rows where [a] Is Not NULL and [bob] Is NULL?

Comment: @Lynette Duffy - no....It is some what like an AND statement. either I get [A] AND [bob] or I get none (null,null). Don't want to get [a] without [bob] and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: This query returns you the result as expected from your sample data -
(Also note, this query is taken with help from Treefrog's answer below) -

```
SELECT t1.[name], t3.a, t2.bob
FROM T2 as t2
JOIN T3 as t3 ON t3.t2_id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN T1 as t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

My Older answer -

```
SELECT a
FROM T1 as t1
INNER JOIN T2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT JOIN T3 as t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id
```

Comment: sorry, but no, this won't enforce the join of t2 and t3 to be only when both have data in them.

Comment: Some people forget we're not telepathic :(

Comment: @Italy Maov - Edited my answer. Also I am trying to help you here. You dont have to downvote me. If you feel its wrong, then you can let me know. Will try to correct it or delete it if it does not help.

Comment: @Sachin Shanbhag - see edited question, I cancelled my down vote (I really consider down votes as something not personal, just marking wrong answer, sorry if I offended you).

Comment: @Itay Moav - Hey no worries. Its just that, it gets a bit frustrating when the one who asked question downvotes even when people are helping him. But anyway, its ok. It was just heat of that moment let out. Sorry and thanks. Let me try to correct the answer.

Comment: @Itay Moav - Edited my answer and also tested with sample data. Its working fine now. Check the EDIT in my answer above.

Comment: thx, this answer is just what i needed... upvoted for simplicity of answer, never though of changing and using right joins

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T1.a
FROM T2
JOIN T3 ON T3.t2_id = T2.id
RIGHT JOIN T1 ON T1.id = T2.t1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these will give you your result. Not sure which would perform better.

NESTED STATEMENT:

```
SELECT [name], NULL AS [a], NULL AS  [bob]
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id 
WHERE t3.t2_id IS NULL
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 AS t1b LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 AS t2b ON t1b.id = t2b.t1_id LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 AS t3b ON t2b.id = t3b.t2_id WHERE t1.id = t1b.id AND t3b.a IS NOT NULL) = 0
UNION
SELECT [name], [a], [bob]
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id 
WHERE t3.t2_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.name
```

TEMPORARY TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_Rslt([name] varchar(50), [a] varchar(50), [bob] varchar(50))

--select matches
INSERT INTO #tmp_Rslt
SELECT [name], [a], [bob]
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id 
WHERE t3.t2_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY t1.name

--select t1's that didn't have matches
INSERT INTO #tmp_Rslt
SELECT [name], NULL AS [a], NULL AS  [bob]
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id 
WHERE t3.t2_id IS NULL
AND t1.[name] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [name] FROM #tmp_Rslt)

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_Rslt

--cleanup.
DROP TABLE #tmp_Rslt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM T1
LEFT JOIN (T2
 INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.id=T3.t2_id
) ON T1.id= T2.t1_id
```